# Do I need to REBUILD my project after changes in web config?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am changing the `DEBUG MODE` to `FALSE` in web config. Should I rebuild my project after changing DEBUG?

**Note:** We have many bins. In order to avoid replacing bins in online I am asking this question.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I suggest you to read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This is the real definition of an unclear question.

Comment: Do you mean when you switch compilation debug="false" to `true`?

Comment: thanks @MatíasFidemraizer for your concern. and yes i am changing compilation from "true" to false.

Comment: @SINDUJA I've already answered you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about `<compilation debug="true">`, no, you don't need to rebuild your solution/project.

This is about [ASP.NET compilatio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229863.aspx)n rather than your regular project compilation. Whenever an ASP.NET application is started, unless it has been published precompiling it, ASP.NET engine will compile your user controls, code-behind code and other areas of your Web application during the first request to your Web site.

Comment: Maybe you should read [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308302/how-to-deal-with-unclear-questions-and-their-lightning-fast-fastest-gun-in-the) once.

Comment: @AlexJolig Do you really think I didn't understand the issue and I've thrown here the first thing that came to my mind? You're wrong, if you have strong experience in some fields like ASP.NET, the question seems absolutely clear and that was my case.

Comment: @AlexJolig Also it's absolutely clear that OP has limited knowledge about ASP.NET and maybe the question isn't composed as we could like more, but after all I didn't need more than 10 seconds to understand what was the issue :D

Answer (score 6):

No. You don't have to rebuild, the config file will be read as is as long as it's saved.